# Invertible Matrix Proof by Given that Other is invertible

Tags: matrices, inverse

Given that $A$ is antisymmetric matrix, and $(I + A)$ it is invertible.

I had to prove that $(I - A)$ is also invertible, and I managed to do so,
But now given that $$C = (I - A)(I + A)^{-1}$$
I have to prove that $$C^\intercal C = I$$

- Without determinants.

I tried many different ways, First tried to prove that C is invertible and to find it's inverse matrix, also tried to find the inverse of the transposed matrix, I have no clue how to continue...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lemma: If $AB=I$, then $BA=I$. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i)

The antisymmetric matrix $A$ means $A^T=-A$.

We first check the value of $CC^T$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
CC^T&=(I-A)(I+A)^{-1}(I+A^T)^{-1}(I-A^T)\\
&=(I-A)(I+A)^{-1}(I-A)^{-1}(I+A)\\
&=(I-A)(I-A^2)^{-1}(I+A)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

It follows from $(I+A)(I-A)(I-A^2)^{-1}=(I-A^2)(I-A^2)^{-1}=I$ and the above lemma that$$(I-A)(I-A^2)^{-1}(I+A)=I.$$

Therefore, $CC^T=I$. Furthermore, $C^TC=I$.

Comment: The thing I was missing is that I been able to commute (change the order).
Now I understand that I was able to do it,
Thanks !